# A definition of velocity vector in the kinematic version of tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $M$ be a manifold, $x\in M$ and $\gamma\colon (-1,1)\to M$ be a smooth curve such that $\gamma(0)=x$.

**Premise** Assume that $T_x M=\{ X\colon C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb R \mid X \text{ is linear and satisfies Leibniz rule at } x\}$. Then I can define
$$\dot\gamma(0)\colon f\in C^\infty(M)\mapsto \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(f\circ \gamma)(t)\in \mathbb R$$

**My question** Let's assume now that $T_xM=\{ [\gamma]_x\mid \gamma\colon (-1,1)\to M,\gamma(0)=x\}$, where two curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\colon (-1,1)\to M$ are said to be equivalent iff there exists a chart $(U,u)$ at $x$ such that
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(u\circ \gamma_1)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(u\circ \gamma_2)$$

With this definition of tangent space, is the following a good definition?
$$\dot \gamma(0):=[\gamma]_{\gamma(0)}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For smooth ($C^\infty$) manifolds both expressions indeed coincide. To be more precise, there is a "canonical" isomorphism between $T_xM$ defined in both ways mapping $\dot\gamma(0)$ to $[\gamma]_{\gamma(0)}$.